# How can I click button to connect my socket with DataOutputStream()

Tags: java, android, sockets

I can't connect button 2 plz tell me how to do this. I never do this ><  I can click button 1 button 2 but it show id button1 only.

```
 package com.app.messageclient;

        import java.io.DataOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.net.UnknownHostException;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MessageClient extends Activity implements OnClickListener {       
        Button button1;
        Button button2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.messageclient);


            button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);

            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

I connect button 1 same this codes and connct to this Socket("10.2.114.192",8080)

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread t=new Thread(){


                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        Socket S=new Socket("10.2.114.192",8080);
                        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeUTF(button1.getText().toString());

                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();
                        S.close();              

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                };
                t.start();
                Toast.makeText(this,"This message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

can I write it to do that??

```
    //Button2
    public void onClick1(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread t=new Thread(){


            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Socket S=new Socket("10.2.114.192",8080);
                    DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeUTF(button2.getText().toString());

                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                    S.close();              

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();
        Toast.makeText(this,"This message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```